# Why Openfire not returning old chats after server restart?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, xmppframework, asmack

Openfire only returns offline messages for a room which are held in server cache. Recently I did a server restart as Openfire was consuming a lot of memory and after that the server is not returning complete chats. It returns on few which are in memory.

I have enable Conversation logging from Openfire console and after a lot of googling came to no solution. I believe XEP-0136 - Message Archiving is not the solution.

Please can anyone provide solution in this regard?